# PRODID in iCAL header

Tags: icalendar

What does the "//EN" in the PRODID means? I've created my own `.ics` file according to the iCalendar specifications (https://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/prodid.html), but I didn't find out what does the "EN" means. Is that country or language identificator with which the event invitation is written? Since that file is written in Czech I wonder if I can use CS or CZ in that. Or do I missing something?

```
PRODID:-//Název firmy//Interní číslo//EN
```

Comment: I am also Czech and we have similar problem now :D

Answer (score 0):

In the original [RFC 2445](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt), section 4.7.3 states that PRODID should contain some globally unique identifier, such as FPI specified in ISO 9070, which is also the format you used. Finally, if you try to read about FPI, you will see that the code at the end of such strings is an uppercase language acronym specified by ISO 639-1. So, in your case, it should be *CS*.

Anyway, I do not think it is something significant. Both RFC 2445 and ISO 9070 state that their format is only recommended. Here is an example from an event sent by Czech Railways where they use acronyms for language and territory together:

```
PRODID:-//CD//NONSGML www.cd.cz//cs-CZ
```